# Edit text is loosing focus automatically in xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-listview, editor

We are working in a xamarin forms application. In which we have a list view where it has two editor , when we are tapping the second editor the focus is switched automatically to the first editor. It works fine in iOS but the issue is mainly in Android devices which are not Samsung. It works as expected in Samsung device. Please help

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug in Xamarin.Forms. I have already reported it [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7168).
You can subscribe to the issue and comment, so that they can fix it quickly. 13 days ago they have moved the issue into `Ready for work`, which means that a fix will come no sooner that *3 months*.

In the meantime, you can "fix" it with replacing the `ListView` with `CollectionView`. At least in my experience, the `CollectionView` doesn't break the focusing this way. If you are still experiencing some focusing issues, the best will be to create a repro project and report the issue, as I have.